# errors during installing dlib windows 10

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, face-detection, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to install the latest version of **`face_recongintion`** library and this package need the **`dlib`** package and while installing **`dlib`**, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I have installed `CMake` also add it to path variable and installed Microsoft visual studio 2015 and also installed MinGW but still the same

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/

Comment: may be try this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777497/how-to-solve-issue-related-to-installation-of-dlib-on-windows-10/58857306#58857306

Comment: I run as it says and it says that this packages installed but when I run pip list command the dlib is not installed. Still getting same error :(

Comment: try to install by using **conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17 ** command and if any clarification refer this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948431/circleci-pip-install-dlib-fails/58706337#58706337

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this didn’t work for me and I have solved the problem by installing visual C++ build tools.